# Ant & how to parse a properties file to echo back the values

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have a properties file that I want to echo out the values

```
<HSMKeys>
<Key domain="default" value="TestA" />
<Key domain="fixed" value="TestB" /> 
</HSMKeys>
```

as

```
[echo] domain=default value=TestA
[echo] domain=fixed value=TestB
```

How can I do this, ie loop over the properties file and have the two variables that would be in the echo.

I have tried the following

```
<for list="${HSMKeys.Key.domain}" param="domain">
<sequential>
<echo>domain=@{domain}</echo>
</sequential>
</for>
```

ie I can only get at one attribute value at a time, not both at once.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @thekbb has stated this is not a properties file, however, ANT supports the [parsing of XML files](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) as properties.

```
<project name="demo" default="print">

  <xmlproperty file="properties.xml"/>

  <target name="print">
    <echoproperties prefix="HSMKeys."/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Produces the following output:

```
print:
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Tue Dec 03 23:44:14 GMT 2013
[echoproperties] HSMKeys.Key=,
[echoproperties] HSMKeys.Key(domain)=default,fixed
[echoproperties] HSMKeys.Key(value)=TestA,TestB
```

May not be exactly what you need but has the advantage of not requiring additional jars like Ant-contrib.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a properties file.  Properties files are key/value pairs.  How are you populating `list`?

a property file ant will understand will look like:

```
domain.default=TestA
domain.fixed=testB
```

I recommend avoiding ant-contrib at all costs... what are you really trying to do?
you could simply use [echoproperties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html)

```
<project name="test" default="echo" basedir=".">

    <property file="build.properties" />

    <target name="echo" >
        <echoproperties prefix="domain."/>
    </target>

</project>
```